# JSON data and Vuetify cards

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I've had no problem binding data to a vuetify data table like so;

```
<template>
  <v-data-table
    :items="items"
    :items-per-page="5"
    class="elevation-1"
  >
    <template v-slot:item="props">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ props.item.title }}</td>
            <td>{{ props.item.content }}</td>
        </tr>
    </template>
  </v-data-table>
</template>
```

However, when attempting to do the same thing with a Vuetify card, I get nothing:

```
<template>
    <v-card :items="items">
      <template  v-slot:item="props">
        <v-card-title>{{ props.item.title }}</v-card-title>
        <v-card-text>{{ props.item.content }}</v-card-text>
      </template>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:

I have updated with my latest attempt below as per responses.

Script:

```
<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  components: {},
  computed: {},
  data() {
    return {
      items: []
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.loadItems(); 
  },
  methods: {
    loadItems() {

      // Init variables
      var self = this
      var app_id = "ID";
      var app_key = "KEY";
      this.items = []
      axios.get(
        "https://api.airtable.com/v0/"+app_id+"/Content",
        { 
          headers: { Authorization: "Bearer "+app_key } 
        }
      ).then(function(response){
        self.items = response.data.records.map((item)=>{
          return {
              id: item.id,
              ...item.fields
          }
        })
      }).catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
      })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

I get `Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.`. I have tried putting it into a parent div or template tag and it still doesn't render.

Comment: Vuetifys Card component doesn't offer the attribute `items` nor an `item` slot. Check out  the API doc of [Data Table](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables/#data-tables) and [Card](https://dev.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/#cards)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`<v-card>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/cards/) component do not accept a prop with such a name (items). This means you will need to hard code the iterations by yourself ([Vue.js list rendering documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html)). Something like this:

```
<v-card
  v-for="item in items" :key="item.title"
  class="mx-auto"
  width="400"
>  
    <v-card-title> {{ item.title }}</v-card-title>  
    <v-card-text> {{ item.content }} </v-card-text>
</v-card>
```

This supposes you have `items` data (just an example):

```
data() {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          title: 'card 1',
          content: 'this is the content of card 1'
        },
        {
          title: 'card 2',
          content: 'this is the content of card 2'
        }
      ]
    }
  },
```

And you will get something like this:

[image]

**Update:**

Following your comment, I can guess the issue you are facing is in the template part of your component. So If we take the example I shared above, this is one way to prevent the error you got:

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row v-for="item in items" :key="item.title">
      <v-col>
        <v-card
          class="mx-auto"
          width="400"
        >  
          <v-card-title> {{ item.title }}</v-card-title>  
          <v-card-text> {{ item.content }} </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
   </v-container>
</v-template>
```

Note that I moved the v-for to the outer `v-row` component so that I can draw one `v-card` per row.

Comment: Thanks Billal, I tried your way and I get: `  Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements.`. I have updated with my script

Comment: You have to wrap the `v-card` within some other component. Please check my edit

Comment: You're the best.  I see, I'll use v-row from now on!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the props directly ?

```
<template>
 <v-card>
    <v-card-title>{{ props.item.title }}</v-card-title>
    <v-card-text>{{ props.item.content }}</v-card-text>
 </v-card>
</template>
```